# Adding a column to a global variable created in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, global

I created subdataframes out of a big dataframe in a loop, and I've been trying to create a column on those subdataframes, inside the loop:

```
Partidas=data2['Partida'].unique()
Partida2=[w.replace(' ','_') for w in Partidas]
for i, j in zip(Partidas,Partida2):
    globals()['%s' % j]=data2.loc[data2['Partida']==i]

for k in globals().items()
    ['%s' % k]['Top 10']='a'
```

So I create one dataframe for every 'Partida' and their name is the name of the 'Partida' they represent. Now I want to add a column to those dataframes called 'Top 10', but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Do you know if there's a way I could add that column inside the loop, without having to go dataframe per dataframe adding the column?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, why are you creating global variables in a loop like this in the first place? Also, what are you expecting that second loop to do?

Answer (score 0):

The proximate problem is that `'%s' % k` is not quite the same thing as `str(k)` but slower—it's:

- The same thing as `str(k)` but slower if `k` is anything but a tuple,
- The same thing as `str(k[0])` if `k` is a one-element tuple, or
- A `TypeError` if `k` is a tuple with any other length.

The `%` operator takes a tuple, but for compatibility with Python ancient 1.2 or so, and for quick&dirty hacking at the interactive terminal, it treats anything that isn't a tuple as a one-element tuple. Which works, except when you actually give it a tuple.

---

If you don't understand why `k` is a tuple—that's exactly what `dict.items()` iterates: key-value tuples.

---

To fix this, you can use `'%s' % (k,)`. This actually *is* the same thing as `str(k)` but slower.

---

But why do you want the same thing as `str(k)` but slower in the first place? Why not just `str(k)`?

---

But then it's not clear why you're trying to do this in the first place, and all it's going to do is give you another `TypeError`.

`[str(item)]` is a list of one string. (The string happens to be a string representation of a key-value tuple out of `globals()`, but that doesn't actually matter here.) You then try to index that list with `'Top 10'`, which obviously isn't an index.

If that error isn't obvious, imagine that you'd written this instead:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst['Top 10'] = 'a'
```

---

Maybe what you wanted is:

```
for k in globals().values():
    k['Top 10'] = 'a'
```

But that isn't going to work either. There are a few more problems to get through, but ultimately you come down to one that can't be solved.

---

`globals()` contains *all* of your globals, not just the ones you created above.

For example, it contains `Partidas`, and `k`, and probably `pd`. And a bunch of other modules you imported and functions you defined and so on. Most of those things are not dicts, dataframes, or other kinds of mappings, so you're just going to get yet another `TypeError`. Worse, a few of them *are* mappings, but not mappings you wanted to add a `'Top 10'` key to, and for those, you'll be corrupting your data silently, instead of getting an error.

---

All of this just demonstrates why you don't want to create a whole bunch of global variables in the first place. If you'd, say, just created one global dict, and stored everything in that, this would all be easy.

Something like this:

```
stuff = {}
for i, j in zip(Partidas,Partida2):
    stuff[j] = data2.loc[data2['Partida']==i]
for k in stuff.values():
    k['Top 10'] = 'a'
```